# The Ajax stopped working on Stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, browser-cache, ajax, scripts

I currently cannot click on add comment, view more comments, vote or see a preview of the answer I am typing.

It work on meta stackoverflow though.

It may be only me, because the power that be insist on using a whitelist internet restriction. Did the source of the ajax script changed since yesterday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your browser lost track of the SO javascript.  Flush browser cache, shift-F5, all that fun stuff to make your browser reload the scripts.  See if that does it for you.

Comment: This was it. I should think about that more often.

Comment: This happens to me aswell when I have facbook open, and someone types to me in the chat box. No idea why, but AJAX apperantly don't like it.